# springboot initialization error on startup with mongodb on gorm/groovy

Tags: spring, mongodb, groovy, grails-orm, spring-boot

Getting startup issues for this [springboot project using MongoDB/GORM/Groovy](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm-mongodb/) on `Java 1.7.0_55`, gradle `1.11`, and `spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE`.

I'm running the project *as-is* with the exception of the following change to `application.yml` for my remote mongodb:

```
spring:
    mongodb:
        host: "10.160.8.1"
        databaseName: "citydb"
```

**On startup, I'm seeing this bean initialization error with `mappingMongoConverter`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoConverter]: : Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMapping
Context] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingCo
ntext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org
/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of typ
e [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappin
gContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingC
ontext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**I think this is the main issue:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resou
rce [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index
1 of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Mon
goMappingContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Mongo
MappingContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
1111)
```

Could this be a GORM dependency issue? I'm using the latest, `org.grails:gorm-mongodb-spring-boot:1.1.0.RELEASE`

Tracked as issue on github: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gorm-mongodb/issues/6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gorm-mongodb-spring-boot` is incompatible with Spring Boot 1.2. It creates a bean named `mongoMappingContext` that prevents `MongoDataAutoConfiguration` from creating its own bean with the same name. You should see a message like this in the log:

```
2015-02-25 14:01:30.731  INFO 60231 --- [           main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=mongoMappingContext,declaringClass=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'mongoMappingContext' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
```

You can work around the problem by declaring your own `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext` bean with a different name, for example:

```
@Bean
MongoMappingContext springDataMongoMappingContext() {
    return new MongoMappingContext()
}
```

Comment: It isn't really something to follow. It's a workaround for a 6-year-old problem with `gorm-mongodb-spring-boot` that's hopefully been fixed by now.